# Node/Mongo autocomplete with search on two fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, autocomplete, promise, nosql

I am using Node/Express/Mongo/Mongoose/jQuery/jQuery UI Auto-complete. I have a collection of Businesses that look like this:

```
[
    {
    name: "Example Corporation",
    "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "state: "NY"
    },
    {
    name: "ABC Corp",
    "address": {
        "city": "Atlanta",
        "state: "GA"
    },
    {
    name: "ACME Inc",
    "address": {
        "city": "Dallas",
        "state: "TX"
    },
    {
    name: "New York Company",
    "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "state: "NY"
    },
    {
    name: "XYZ Co",
    "address": {
        "city": "Newark",
        "state: "NJ"
    }
}
]
```

I want to create an auto-complete that would allow someone to type in the partial name of the business name OR city and get results back grouped like so:

If I search `"New"` I want:

```
{
    businesses: [
       {
       name: "New York Company",
       address: {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY"
           }
       },
       {
       name: "XYZ Co",
       address: {
           "city": "Newark",
           "state": "NJ"
           }
       }
    ],
    cities: [
       {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY"
       },
       {
           "city": "Newark",
           "state": "NJ"
       }
    ]
}
```

Very similar to an auto-complete search you might see on OpenTable where you can search by restaurant or location. **I want unique city names returned.**

Do I need to search the collection twice per business name and city and tie it all together at the end? I'm so confused. I don't need ID's back since the end result they either go to a City page or the Business page. I hope this makes sense.